# How splice() is working in angularjs filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, array-splice

```js
"data":[
  {"name":"Boots","description":"High Quality football boots","category":"Football","price":500,"id":"28198b61e64abae1"},
  {"name":"Jersey Kit","description":"Official team jersey","category":"Fashion","price":1200,"id":"5381a6769985d838"},
  {"name":"Bottle","description":"High quality made water bottle","category":"Health","price":20,"id":"f743ce619c57c830"},
  {"name":"Gloves","description":"High quality gloves for best GKs in the world","category":"Football","price":650,"id":"9ef69a59000b3838"},
  {"name":"Bag","description":"Training kit bag","category":"Training","price":20,"id":"07e192edb2f63aed"},
  {"name":"Socks","description":"Best quality","category":"Health","price":60,"id":"d642e7ffa7145b5b"},
  {"name":"EPL official match ball","description":"Light weight football","category":"Football","price":75,"id":"7df38a6c46e5f8ef"}, 
  {"name":"Whistle","description":"Light weight for referees","category":"Football","price":5,"id":"0f3d94d798804b4d"},
  {"name":"Nets","description":"High quality nets","category":"Training","price":50,"id":"4e3d61a7a124e9db"},
  {"name":"Stop watch","description":"Best in quality","category":"Training","price":120,"id":"b86bfb7b0b3c6ac6"}
]
```

I am using AngularJs `$filter` like so: `return $filter("limitTo")(data.splice(3),size);`

The splice() returns an array starting with the element from index no 3, rather than removing the elements from index no 3. Please explain.

Comment: what you want as output array?

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular really, its just javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: I am getting the output array from index no 3 to index no 9. But I am not able to understand how it is working.

Comment: @Magrangs yes you are right. I have checked the link you mentioned. But in my above mentioned it is working differently. If you could explain it would be really helpful.

Comment: @adi Splice will return you the elements that have been removed from the array. It also changes the original array.

Comment: so you need output like this.{"name":"Gloves","description":"High quality gloves for best GKs in the world","category":"Football","price":650,"id":"9ef69a59000b3838"},
 to {"name":"Stop watch","description":"Best in quality","category":"Training","price":120,"id":"b86bfb7b0b3c6ac6"}] ????

Comment: @adi Please see this jsfiddle which will hopefully explain it. https://jsfiddle.net/63ksne7g/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `splice` use angular `filter` for it,

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthbendra/qz5xbkn5/

In controller,

```
$filter("limitTo")($scope.data, 3, 3)
```

View

```
{{data | limitTo:3:3}}
```

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use angular filter

```
var removeItem = data.filter(function(key,val) { return val < 3; });
var remainingItem = data.filter(function(key,val) { return val >= 3; });
console.log(removeItem);
console.log(remainingItem);
```